# Angular: Map the httpClient Json list response to Typescript Class

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I am trying to map the Json response to a Typescript class in Angular.

Json Response: `[{"id":1,"nodeName":"Root","parentNodeId":null,"value":100.0,"children":[]}]`

Although when I run locally I don't see error but the list is still undefined when I try to print on stackblitz, I see below error:

```
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad
```

Although I have checked that my Json on [Json Lint](https://jsonlint.com/) it is a Valid Json.

Typescript Class:

```
export class Node {
 id?: number;
 nodeName?: string;
 parentNodeId?: any;
 value?: number;
 children?: any[];
}
```

Component.ts Code:

```
public nodes: Node[];
constructor(private nodeService: NodeService) {}

getAllNodes() {
  this.nodeService.getListOfNodes().subscribe((data) => {
  console.log('response==>', data);
  this.nodes = data;
});
 console.log('nodes ====>', this.nodes);
}
```

[image: Error]

[StackBlitz Editor Url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-62z9vq?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/node.ts) and [StackBlitz Application Url](https://angular-ivy-62z9vq.stackblitz.io)

Comment: What does your raw JSON string look like if you print it to the console without calling `JSON.parse`?

Comment: @j_m4rtinez I cannot convert <Node[]> to string directly as it gives error, so I have changed to <any> type and there is error: 
ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Your mock data file is `api/api.json` but the URL you are trying to request from is `api/api-data.json` (in your NodeService class). Try making them the same.

Comment: @j_m4rtinez Thanks for noticing, I might have made mistake while copy and pasting. I have corrected it but I am still having issue, not sure what mistake I am still making.

Comment: is it the same exact error as the one posted in your screenshot above?

Comment: @j_m4rtinez yes still the same error.

Comment: It looks like the response is not even in JSON format. In your application window, with the app running, try typing `fetch('api/api.json').then(res => res.text()).then(console.log)
` into the browser console and inspect the result. It's just a webpage. I wonder if Angular is messing with your api.json file because it's within your `app` directory. Maybe try moving your `api` directory outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a new folder `assets` on the same level as your `app` folder, then move the `api.json` file into the `asset` folder.

Next, modify the node retrieval like this:

```
getListOfNodes(): Observable<Node[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Node[]>('/assets/api.json')
}
```

The nodes should now load.